# TMUX 3.2a using send-keys executes the command in the wrong pane

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to setup a shell script that will start a Tmux session, create 2 panes and name them (and eventually run an additional command). The issue I'm running into is the send-keys seems to send the command to the correct pane, but it doesn't seem to actually execute the command in that pane.

```
#!/bin/sh

session="testing"

# set up tmux
tmux start-server
tmux new-session -d -s $session
tmux set pane-border-status top

# Name pane 0
tmux send-keys -t 0 "tmux select-pane -T Unit/Alarm1" Enter

# Split pane 0 horizontal by 34%, name pane 1
tmux splitw -h -p 67
tmux send -t 1 "tmux select-pane -T Unit/Alarm2" Enter

tmux attach-session -t $session
```

After running the script these are the results I get.

[script results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qo98.png)

What am I missing?

I tried using `C-m` instead of `Enter` but have the same result.

When I do the steps manually (not using the script) I find that `tmux send-keys -0 "..." Enter` will send the keys to the correct pane, but it executes the command on the current pane (if I'm in pane 1, it renames pane 1, not pane 0).

[Manual steps before executon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXfmB.png)

[Manual steps after execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyBIe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send keys to a pane that isn't the active pane, but `select-pane` command doesn't refer to the pane the command is run in. By default, `select-pane` will refer to the active pane. I expected that the pane you most recently created was the active pane, but it's possible there's a race condition between your send-keys command returning and your next command executing, or that something else is going on that I don't understand.

Regardless, you can avoid these issues (and make your script simpler) by using `-t` to point to the right pane, like

```bash
# Name pane 0
tmux select-pane -t .0 -T "Unit/Alarm1"

# Split pane 0 horizontal by 34%, name pane 1
tmux splitw -h -p 67
tmux select-pane -t .1 -T "Unit/Alarm2"
```

If you want to be more specific, you can target different tmux sessions or windows with `select-pane`, like

```bash
tmux select-pane -t $SESSION:$WINDOW.$PANE -T "$PANE_NAME"
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it was so easy to name a pane.